# How do I get debug information from a function?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I've used Clang to compile a function with debug information enabled. For `Instruction`s there's the handy `getDebugLoc()`, but there's no such thing for `Function`s. Given a `Function` instance, how can I get the debug information (I'm guessing in `DISubProgram` form) for it?

I've seen [the guide entry explaining how that debug information is represented](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#subprogram-descriptors), and the metadata does contain a link back to the function, but there's apparently no link back. Am I supposed to iterate over all the metadata in the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's currently an easier way. There used to be a global metadata node that collected all function metadata entries (`llvm.dbg.sp`) but it was removed a while ago in favor of `llvm.dbg.cu` which reflects the DWARF structure more closely.

I suppose that the common uses of debug metadata don't require by-function lookup, and any extra information that could be removed, *was* removed, because saving space is important and metadata in IR is already way too big.

Answer (score 10):

I think you need to use the DebugInfoFinder. Here is a sample code:

```
DebugInfoFinder Finder;
Finder.processModule(M);
for (DebugInfoFinder::iterator i = Finder.subprogram_begin(),
                    e = Finder.subprogram_end();
                    i != e; ++i) {
                DISubprogram S(*i);

                if (S.getFunction() == F) {
                    errs() << S.getLineNumber(); << "\n";
                }
            }
```

where F is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Newer versions of LLVM provide a getSubprogram() function, as mentioned by zhiqiu

Answer (score 8):

you can use getSubprogram() as describled in [doxygen: Function class](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a4d834f9897d15e3a6349063b5d637cd8)