# LLVM Pass to Parse Debug Info

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I've been writing some different LLVM passes to learn more about the system and I've run into something that I can't seem to find a definitive reference on: is there any way to iterate over all the debug symbols in an IR file when they're available?

In particular, I'd like to be able to parse this:

`!6 = distinct !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_structure_type, name: "conf_struct", file: !7, line: 3, size: 64, elements: !8)`

I've tried using the `llvm::DebugInfoFinder` and that has methods to return counts/etc. but it doesn't seem to have anything to return data on a `DICompositeType`.

I thought there might be something of use in `getIdentifiedStructTypes` but that doesn't seem to get any of the metadata associated with the structs.

Thank you for any guidance with this!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351299/how-do-i-get-debug-information-from-a-function